# Deploy app on iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch

Tags: ios, certificate, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to develop an app and I want to deploy this app to my iPhone, but I'm having issue.
I'm using as administrator an AppleID connected to the develop center. So I need to add this iPhone to the developer portal.
If I read well on the web, I understand that I've to generate a certificate and upload it to the developer center. I generated the certificate by using keychain on my MacBook Pro, then I surf the web to reach the developer portal. When I'm in the developer portal, I made this operation:

1. Login with my username and my password
2. I clicked on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"
3. I clicked on "Certificates"
4. I clicked on the button "+" in the top bar

Here I'm having issue, because I can't add a certificate like "developer", why I can't add another certificate to this account? I can use the certificate that it's still online?
I post here a picture to explain you what's my issue:

[image: Screenshot of my Certificates site]

**UPDATE:**

To connect my device to this developer profile, I tried to make this steps:

1. I added the iPhone in the section "Device"
2. I clicked on the section "Provisioning Profiles"
3. I clicked on the button "+"
4. I choose the kind of certificate I need (iOS App Development)
5. I choose an App ID
6. I choose the certificate
7. I downloaded the file generated
8. I clicked on this file and it open Xcode Organizer

Here I'm having issue: when I go to Organizer -> Provisioning Profile, I see the profile I generated, but it says "Valid signing identity not found".
What's wrong with my steps?

Here's the pic in which you can see my issue:

[image]

Comment: I think there is only one developer certificate is Sufficient for developing the apps. Why do you need another developer certificate?

Comment: Ok, which steps I should do to obtain a certificate to deploy my app on my iPhone with this developer profile?

Comment: First generate the AppId of your App & then Generate the Provisioning Profile.

Comment: You need a provisioning profile for the app and you need to add the iPhone to the Devices list

Comment: Look to my question I've updated it

Comment: have you downloaded the existing certificate and installed it in your keychain on your mac?

Comment: sure, I've installed it